# Calculating the Sum of the Fibonacci Sequence Using Recursion MATLAB

Tags: matlab, recursion, fibonacci

So I am having a little issue with recursion. I see there are a lot of questions in regards to finding the Fibonacci sequence using recursion, but I figured that out(for the most part) on my own. What I am struggling with, however, is trying to find the sum of all of the fibonnaci numbers up until a certain value. For instance, if I input the number 3, I should get four. If I input the number 10, my total should be 143. So basically:

```
 Test Cases:
  out1 = sumFib(3);
   out1 = 4;

   out2 = sumFib(10);
   out2 = 143;

   out3 = sumFib(28);
   out3 = 832039
```

I'm struggling a little understanding how to get the base case (or terminating factor). Here is what I have so far for my code:

```
function out = sumFib(n)

if n==1 || n==2
    out = 1;
   else
    out =sumFib(n-1) + sumFib(n-2) ;
    %// Gives us the value of n-1 and adds it to the value of n-2

end

end
```

This gives me what the value of the number is at the nth position. To find the total sum, I've tried the following

```
if n==3
out = 4
else
out = sumFib(n) + sumFib(n - (n-1))
```

As you cna imagine, this flags me with

```
"Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached. Use set(0,'RecursionLimit',N) to change the limit. Be aware that exceeding your available stack space can crash MATLAB and/or your computer."
```

I've also tried to do:

```
function out = sumFib(n)

if n==1 || n==2
    out = 1;
   else
    out =(1+sumFib(n-1)) + sumFib(n-2) ;
    %Gives us the value of n-1 and adds it to the value of n-2
```

And using the correct sum aspect for the Fibonacci sequence

```
if n==3
        out = 4;
    else
       out = sumFib(n+2)-1;
end
```

Here the 1 is my attempt to let the problem know to move on to the next number, but that doesn't work. If anyone could better explain the base condition to me and help, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Do you *have* to use recursion? Somewhere on Stackoverflow I think I saw a vectorized version of it. I might be dreaming about it though.

Comment: I have to use recursion. I tried to do the array version actually, but that didn't quite work with what I was trying to do. Or I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: note the following: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Sequence_of_Fibonacci_Numbers

Comment: `Fib(n+2)-1`, as @Amro mentioned.

Comment: I've tried that, but I still get the same error. Updated my code. I'm not sure how/where to put in the base case. How to make it realize what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep it simple, and split the functions in two:

```
function out = fib_sum(n)
    out = fib(n+2) - 1;
end

function out = fib(n)
    if n < 2
        out = n;
    else
        out = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
    end
end
```

(of course I'm assuming non-negative integer numbers)

Comment: You know, I really hate when I over complicate things. That's ten times easier than what I was thinking. And it makes sense. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work as well if you input the integer one less than the one you have in the test cases -

```
function out = sumFib(n)

if n < 2
    out = n;
else
    out = sumFib(n-1) + sumFib(n-2);
end
out = 1 + out;

return;
```

The trick was to get that summation - `plus 1` out of the conditional statement.

Sample runs -

```
>> out1 = sumFib(2)
out1 =
     4
>> out1 = sumFib(9)
out1 =
   143
>> out1 = sumFib(27)
out1 =
      832039
```

Of course you can wrap it with another function, in which you can do that `input-integer minus 1` operation, if you intend to make it work for the exact integers, as you had in your test cases.